# Adding a circle around a vertex of a graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, graphs

I have the following code that produces the following image:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
dot/.style = {circle, fill, minimum size=3pt, 
              inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}    
                        ]
\foreach \i in {1,2,3,4}
{
    \foreach \j in {1,2,3,4}
\node (n\i\j) [dot] at (\i,\j) {};
}
\scoped[on background layer]
{
\draw[red]  (n11) -- (n44)
            (n24) -- (n31)
            (n21) -- (n34)
            (n13) -- (n42)
            (n23) -- (n32)
            (n43) -- (n12);
            
            
}
\node[below left] at (n14) {$v$};
\node[above right] at (n41) {$\overline{v}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

I was wondering if there would be a way of adding a blue (or any color) circle around the vertices $v$ and $\overline{v}$? The dot should remain there but just simply be surrounded by a relatively small blue circle. [image]

Comment: Please add a working example that compiles.

Answer (score 2):

The key was adding these two lines:

```
\path[draw=blue] (n14) circle[radius=0.1];
\path[draw=blue] (n41) circle[radius=0.1];
```

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
dot/.style = {circle, fill, minimum size=3pt, 
              inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}    
                        ]
\foreach \i in {1,2,3,4}
{
    \foreach \j in {1,2,3,4}
\node (n\i\j) [dot] at (\i,\j) {};
}
%\scoped[on background layer]
{
\draw[red]  (n11) -- (n44)
            (n24) -- (n31)
            (n21) -- (n34)
            (n13) -- (n42)
            (n23) -- (n32)
            (n43) -- (n12);
            
            
}
\node[below left] at (n14) {$v$};
\node[above right] at (n41) {$\overline{v}$};
\path[draw=blue] (n14) circle[radius=0.1];
\path[draw=blue] (n41) circle[radius=0.1];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]