# Drawing points with sqrt values in a graph on tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, diagrams, graphs

I am struggling with drawing the following set of coordinates:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (a1) at (0,(1+{sqrt(\5)})^{2}/2);
    \coordinate (a2) at (0,2);
    \coordinate (a3) at (0,1);
    \coordinate (a4) at (2,1);
    \coordinate (a5) at (1,2);
    
    \node[points, anchor=north] at (0,(1+{sqrt(\5)})^{2}/2) {};
    \node[points, anchor=north] at (0,2) {};
    \node[points, anchor=west] at (0,1) {};
    \node[points, anchor=north] at (2,1) {};
    \node[points, anchor=east] at (1,2) {};


\draw[black] (a1) -- (a2) {};
\draw[black] (a1) -- (a3) {};
\draw[black] (a1) -- (a4) {};
\draw[black] (a1) -- (a5) {};
\draw[black] (a2) -- (a3) {};
\draw[black] (a2) -- (a4) {};
\draw[black] (a2) -- (a5) {};
\draw[black] (a3) -- (a4) {};
\draw[black] (a3) -- (a5) {};
\draw[black] (a4) -- (a5) {};


\node[dotnode] at (a1) {};
\node[dotnode] at (a2) {};
\node[dotnode] at (a3) {};
\node[dotnode] at (a4) {};
\node[dotnode] at (a5) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The code seems to work fine if I remove the point a1. However, I would like a1 to have the value $\frac{(1+\sqrt{5})^{2}}{2}$, and I've tried several different expressions to obtain this value, including writing \5, \sqrt etc, but I cannot seem to get this to work. Is there a way to do it without having to write an approximate value?

Comment: Is `\coordinatex` a specific command or is it a typo? (3rd line of your Ti*k*Z code)

Comment: That's a typo, I will fix that

Comment: Please, convert your code fragment to complete, compilable small document. We dont know what is `points`, and `dotnote` nor what the drawing result should be.

Comment: BTW, code line `\coordinate (a1) at (0,(1+{sqrt(\5)})^{2}/2);` should be replaced by `\coordinate (a1) at (0,{0.5*(1+sqrt(5))^2});` and similarly `\node[points, anchor=north] at (0,(1+{sqrt(\5)})^{2}/2) {};` with `\node[points, anchor=north] at (0,{0.5*(1+sqrt(5))^2}) {};`.

Answer (score 1):

- Have a look at Chapter 13.5 of the [`pgf` manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf).
- **I think that `sqrt(\5)` cannot work since `\5` is not a valid command.**
- **In addition, you need `$` when using the `calc` library.**
- Next time, please provide an MWE: [I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228) as also pointed out in one of your [previous questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595036).

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0, 0) {node1};
\node at ($({sqrt(1)}, {sqrt(1)})$) {node2}; % Watch out for the right amount of "()".
\node at ($({sqrt(2)}, {sqrt(2)})$) {node3};
\node at ($({sqrt(4)}, {sqrt(4)})$) {node4};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: calc and $ $ is not required

Answer (score 1):

I think that @DrManuel does't fully answer the OP.

If you make a computation of a *single* coordinate (here the `y` of `a1`), you don't need neither the `calc` library nor the `$...$` syntax.
But the expression, when containing parentheses, must be protected in `{...}`. Without this precaution, the closing `)` would be interpreted as the end of the `(x,y)` part.

Here you made a mixture of pgfmath *computation* and standard formula *typesseting* (namely unneeded extra braces, and `sqrt` to compute the square root, while `\sqrt` is nonsense here, and likely triggers an error).

As a result, your should write

```
\coordinate (a1) at (0,{(1+sqrt(5))^2/2});
```

Notice that:

- Oppositely to `\node` (or `node` in a path),  the neither the command `\coordinate` nor `\draw` expect an extra argument, hence all of your empty `{}` are useless (if not faulty).
- Finally, as partially suggested in  @DrManuel answer, all your `\node`s and  `\coordinate`s are strongly  redundant. A shorter and better coding would only involve:

  `\node[points, anchor=north] (a1) at (0,{(1+sqrt(5))^2/2}) {};`

and similarly for the next points.

EDIT: Anyway, I would use:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\MYCOORDY{(1+sqrt(5))^2/2}
```

and use the so-defined macro `\MYCOORDY` in the node definitions or, even better:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\Golden{(1+sqrt(5))/2}
\node[points, anchor=north] (a1) at (0,1+\Golden) {};
```

Comment: I'm sure that my comment solve OP problems (as far as can be concluded from lack of information  :-) .

Comment: @Zarko, for sure, I agree, but some explanalion seems always useful, and by the way, I was already writing my answer went you posted your comment ;-)